# Can I avoid source formatting with the listings package?

Tags: listings

Is there a way to use the listings environment, without resorting to a specific language formatting? (but instead use the usual Latex commands being formatted correctly.)

The reason I want to do it is because I want to use a specific feature in the listings package (line numbering) for regular text.

EDIT: Here is a MWE that doesn't work for me:

```
 \documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{tcolorbox}
 \usepackage{lineno}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tcolorbox}[middle=0mm,boxsep=0mm]

 \begin{linenumbers}

 \begin{itemize}
 \item x
 \item y
 \end{itemize}

 \end{linenumbers}

 \end{tcolorbox}

 \end{document}
```

What I want to have is a line number next to each line in the itemized list, appearing on the left margin *inside* the tcolorbox environment. Is there a way to do it? (right now no line numbers appear at all.)

Comment: Have you considered the `lineno` package? It provides line numbering for regular text.

Comment: @dcmst the problem is that lineno does it at a global way for the whole document. I want to do it for a constrained environment, limited in scope.

Comment: the line numbering can be made local enclosing `\linenumbers` into a group or using the `linenumbers` env.

Comment: @dcmst I wasn't aware of this environment, but it is not working for me. see MWE in my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like the following, what you need is the `internallinenumbers` macro:

```
\documentclass{article}

 \usepackage{tcolorbox}
 \usepackage{lineno}

 \begin{document}

 \begin{tcolorbox}[middle=0mm,boxsep=0mm]
  \setlength\linenumbersep{1cm} %sets the distance of the line numbers from the margin
  \begin{internallinenumbers}
   \begin{itemize}
    \item x
    \item y
   \end{itemize}
  \end{internallinenumbers}
 \end{tcolorbox}
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Or if you want the number to be printed inside the tcolorbox, just change the value of `linenumbersep`:

```
 \begin{tcolorbox}[middle=0mm,boxsep=0mm]
  \setlength\linenumbersep{-.1cm} %sets the distance of the line numbers from the margin
  \begin{internallinenumbers}
   \begin{itemize}
    \item x
    \item y
   \end{itemize}
  \end{internallinenumbers}
 \end{tcolorbox}
```

[image]

You need to be careful if you put line numbers inside as they can overlap with the box content.

**Edit.**

To change the style of the numbers use:

```
\renewcommand\linenumberfont{\normalsize} % will set the font to \normalsize, add the code you need
```

To add a semi-colon after the numbers use:

```
\renewcommand\thelinenumber{\arabic{linenumber};}
```

Comment: thanks, that could work for me. in attempt to make it more "elegant" -- is there any way to set the linenumbersep logically (relative to the frame of the tcolorbox) instead of having to set it with a specific absolute distance? also, is there a way to increase the font of the numbers slightly and add semicolons after the numbers?

Comment: @kloop the `\linenumbersep` **already is** relative to the frame of the tcolorbox. If you don't set it you'll see that it goes exactly over the frame. So `1cm` means "1cm left of the frame" and `-1cm` means "1cm right of the frame". For the other questions see the edited answer.